# "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'WebSocketCommonProtocol.send' was never awaited" when sending message with Python websocket and RabbitMQ

Tags: python, websocket, async-await, rabbitmq

I'm currently struggling with the implementation of a simple chat using Flask, RabbitMQ and Python websocket.

I have 3 Docker containers for my back, my front and a RabbitMQ image that work well. In parallel I execute a script in which the messages from the RabbitMQ queue are consumed and sent to the front via websocket in the callback (code below).

After several tries, `ws.send(message)` in `send_websocket()` still doesn't work.

My error here is : `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'WebSocketCommonProtocol.send' was never awaited ws.send(message)`

When I add `async` and `await` keywords in `send_websocket()`, the error is `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send_websocket' was never awaited send_websocket(body)`

I tried to use `asyncio.run(ws.send(message))` but the connection closes without sending the message.

I tried to use `asyncio.create_task(ws.send(message))` but I got `RuntimeError: no running event loop` and `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'WebSocketCommonProtocol.send' was never awaited`. Do I need to create a loop ?

```
import pika, threading
import asyncio
import websockets

global_ws_array = []

#### RabbitMQ callback 
def send_websocket(message):
    for ws in global_ws_array:
        print("Send message", message)
        ws.send(message)


#### Websocket callback
async def ws_handler(websocket, path):
    global_ws_array.append(websocket)
    print("Length array", len(global_ws_array))


#### RabbitMQ launch
def receive_message_queue(queue_name, url="amqp://rabbitmq:rabbitmq@localhost/%2f"):

    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters(url))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable=True)


    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):  
        send_websocket(body)


    channel.basic_consume(
        queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

    mq_recieve_thread = threading.Thread(target=channel.start_consuming)
    mq_recieve_thread.start()

receive_message_queue("chat")


#### Websocket server launch
start_server = websockets.serve(ws_handler, "0.0.0.0", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Would you know where my mistake came from? Thanks for your help !!

Comment: You might want to do `await ws.send(message)`

Comment: When I do it I have `'await' outside async function`, and when I add also async before `def send_websocket` I have `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send_websocket' was never awaited   send_websocket(body)`

Comment: Any function that has an `await` inside has to be an `async` function, and every `async` function has to be awaited one way or the other. You may have to change your code to reflect the same.

Comment: Do you know how I could make `send_websocket` to be awaited ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `await` while sending the data from the WebSockets. It will expect to be awaited and make the method to be `async`.

```
#### RabbitMQ callback 
async def send_websocket(message):
    for ws in global_ws_array:
        print("Send message", message)
        await ws.send(message)
```